# How to display Local notification message in UILabel?

Tags: ios

I need to display Local notification message on the Label. I know the syntax on how to handle notification when the app is running.

Like this on my AppDelegate.m,

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif {

NSLog(@"Recieved Notification %@",notif);


}
```

Looks fine, and i can get the log info.
How to display the message in the label from the AppDelegate?. ex like this.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif {

NSLog(@"Recieved Notification %@",notif);

//Like this concept
MessageLabel.Text = FromNotificationMessage;

}
```

Please help me. I am interested in iOS programming. How to do that?

Comment: Where is this MessageLabel? In which class? You need to store this message in global variable or any variable of that class and show that string in you label.

Comment: Something like this? `MessageLabel.Text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Recieved Notification %@",notif];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the `–application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` you could post a next notification, and every of your classes, which is an observer, can receive it; even the `UIViewController` classes.

an in any of your `UIViewController` class can put the text into a `UILabel` or wherever you'd just like to put.

---

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)note {

    NSString *_stringFromNotification = note.alertBody;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MyPersonalNotification" object:_stringFromNotification];

}
```

---

in any of your `UIVIewController` class:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:@"MyPersonalNotification" object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
        NSString *_string = note.object;
        // ... do whatever you'd like to do with the string
    }];
}
```

---

*NB: that is just one of the possible solutions, and it is very plain representataion of the idea.*

Comment: Thanks @holex. Very nice representation for Local notification. Are they the same with push notification?. On the way on how to get the message from a notification.

Comment: @JakeDuldulao, yes, it is quite similar, not the same, but receiving notifications is very similar.

Comment: @holex This is indeed a nice solution. But the issue is that when the application is killed. The didReceiveLocalNotification is executed before the viewDidLoad of the UIViewController. Then the postNotificationName is executed before the addObserverForName and the function is never triggered.

Comment: I found one solution for getting those notifications even if the app is killed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20164560/handle-uilocalnotification-in-uiviewcontroller-using-nsnotification-after-the-ap

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif {

    NSLog(@"Recieved Notification %@",notif);

    UILabel * MessageLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    MessageLabel.frame = CGRectMake(90, 10, 470, 57);
    MessageLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    MessageLabel.text = notif; // put your message String here.
    [self.window addSubview: MessageLabel];

}
```

Comment: the `AppDelegate` class should not interfere the _view-layer_ like this.

Answer (score 0):

It depends where do you want to show the label with the message of notification. If the label is with any particular UIView and corresponding controller, you need to get the reference of the controller in your application delegate. Once you do this you need to arrive at the label through Controller -> View -> subview(label). Now you can set the label text in the app delegate notification received method.