# Handle UILocalNotification in UIViewController using NSNotification after the app has been terminated

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uilocalnotification, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

I'm working with `UILocalNotification` and I would like to notify one of my controller that the notification has been received even if the app has been terminated.

In my appDelegate I implemented this function:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    if ([application applicationState] == UIApplicationStateInactive) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"localNotificationReceived" object:notification.userInfo];
    }
}
```

In my `UIViewController` I implemented the observer on the `viewDidLoad` method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didlocalNotificationReceived:) name:@"localNotificationReceived" object:nil];   

}
```

It works perfectly when the app run in background. Since the `viewDidLoad` method has already been called and the Observer is waiting..

The issue is when I kill the app. Then the observer of my controller is gone and the `didlocalNotificationReceived` method is never called.

I think that it's because when I receive the `localNotification` and run the app again. The `didReceiveLocalNotification:` method is called before the `viewDidLoad` of my `UIViewController`. Then the observer is created after the `PostNotificationName` then the observer receives nothing.

I would like to know if there is some best practices or pattern to handle this kind of issue.

I know that the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method is called before `didlocalNotificationReceived` so there is probably something to do there.

UPDATE :

I also discovered that when is app is terminated. Once you tap the notification, It opens the app, call the function `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` but never call `didReceiveLocalNotification`. So I think that I'm gonna handle both cases differently.

Comment: Try forcing the load of the view in didDinishLaunching (by accessing the view property). See if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found the answer.

I actually, initialize manually my storyboard, and be cautious that I initialize my main view before posting the `NSNotification`

My `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method in my `appDelegate` looks like that:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    UIViewController *vc =[storyboard instantiateInitialViewController]; //call the initWithCoder: method of my controller

    if (launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey]) {
        UILocalNotification *localNotification = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"localNotificationReceived" object:localNotification.userInfo];
    }

    self.window.rootViewController = vc;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Then in my `UIViewController` I create the `NSNotification` observer in the `initWithCoder:` method instead of in `viewDidLoad:`

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didlocalNotificationReceived:) name:@"localNotificationReceived" object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didlocalNotificationReceived:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    //Execute whatever method when received local notification
}
```

And when the app is not killed I still use the `didReceiveLocalNotification:` method:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    if ([application applicationState] == UIApplicationStateInactive) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"localNotificationReceived" object:notification.userInfo];
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if it's the best practice. But it works well !

Hope it'll help :)